# Unpermitted parameters - Rails 4.1.1, Ruby 2.1.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

I cannot seem to get to the bottom of where I am going wrong. My "order.rb" fields populate ok, but I can't get the "order_row" table values to populate. I just keep getting the following error in terminal(not worried about date for now, should be ok with that)...

Unpermitted parameters: date(i), order_row

Customer model(customer.rb)...

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Order model(order.rb)...

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :order_rows, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_rows
end
```

Order_Row model(order_row.rb)

```
class OrderRow < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end
```

(orders_controller.rb)....

```
def new
  @order = Order.new
end

def create
  @order = Order.new(order_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @order.save
      format.html { redirect_to(@order, :notice => 'Order was successfully created.') }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
    end
  end
end

private
  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:customer_id, :date, :total, 
      :order_row_attributes => [:description, :quantity, :price, :order_id])
  end
```

Form code on new.html.haml

```
= semantic_form_for @order do |f|
  = f.input :customer_id, :as => :select, :collection => Hash[Customer.all.map{|c|  [c.company,c.id]}]
  = f.input :date
  = f.fields_for :order_row do |ff|
    = ff.input :description
    = ff.input :quantity
    = ff.input :price
    = ff.hidden_field :order_id
  = f.input :total
  = f.action :submit, :as => :button
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line **`order_row_attributes`**.It should be **`order_rows_attributes`**. And with the **`date`** not being permitted,try changing the **`date`** attribute to some name like **`order_date`**.

This should work

```
private
  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:customer_id, :order_date, :total, 
    :order_rows_attributes => [:description, :quantity, :price, :order_id])
  end
```

Comment: Thanks Pavan. Yeah I see problem now thanks. I changed to ":order_rows_attributes" but still doesn't populate(it was still saying "order_row" in output), so on "order.rb" i changed "accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_rows" to "accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_row", but then the fields disappear from my form. Must have gone wrong naming, will start over.

Comment: when looping through "order_rows" fields on form view, I have "= f.fields_for :order_row do |ff|". SHouldn't it be "order_rows"? But if i change it to "order_rows" those fields disappear from the view/ form.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing the new method to....

```
def new
  @order = Order.new
  @order.order_rows.build
end
```

So combination of this and Pavans answer did the trick.